# How do I catch an error in Firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, promise, firebase-authentication

I have a Vue news app with a registration page that saves user to firebase.

When the authentication fails and there is an error (e.g. password is not long enough) why does the code continue with the .then() and reroute to the login page? Why does it not go to .catch()? I would like the error to be alerted in case of failure, and for the user to proceed to login page only if/when registration is successful.

```
    pressed(){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(this.$router.replace({name: "LoginPage"}))
        .catch(err=>{
            alert(err)
        })
    },
```

Comment: It should be `.then(() => this.$router.replace({name: "LoginPage"}))`.

Comment: i.e. you pass a **function** to `.then`